# Is there a way to reset Windows XP administrator password?

Tags: windows, password, system

Can I reset a [Windows XP administrator password](http://www.windowspasswordrecovery.net/article/recover-lost-windows-xp-password.html)?

How would I do it?

Comment: You might prefer to use Ubuntu to make Windows XP give you unlimited access from its login screen (which you should of course reverse, once you're done using it). You can search the web for `sethc.exe` to see how to do this. Such a method wouldn't really relate to Ubuntu, except that you'd be using Ubuntu to (temporarily) replace one file with another (inside the Windows system) to accomplish it.

Comment: @Jason  - given that you rolled back the edit, I can only presume that you are not interested in resetting from Ubuntu.  As such, this is off-topic for this Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 5):

You can use chntpw

Assuming you have a dual boot with windows and ubuntu.

First you need to install chntpw

```
  apt-get install chntpw
```

mount your Windows Partition writeable

Goto the following directory (assuming you mounted your windows partition to /mnt)

```
  cd /mnt/WINDOWS/system32/config

  chntpw -u Administrator SAM
```

SAM is the file where the password is stored. You should set it to an empty one choosing option 1

```
    - – - – User Edit Menu:
   1 – Clear (blank) user password
   2 – Edit (set new) user password (careful with this on XP or Vista)
   3 – Promote user (make user an administrator)
   (4 – Unlock and enable user account) [seems unlocked already]
   q – Quit editing user, back to user select
```

Reboot to windows Login as Administator without password :-)

Comment: Using **chntpw** is like using a 200lb sledgehammer *to crack a walnut*. Google: **`ubuntu reset windows 7 password`** & look for *wikihow* results.

Answer (score 3):

> If you have forgotten your administrator password for Windows, you can
>   use a Ubuntu Linux live CD or live USB to reset the password. This
>   tutorial will show you how to do that, step by step.

<sup>Source: [psychocats](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/resetwindowspassword/)</sup>

[Take a look at this site](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/resetwindowspassword/)

Also there are many ways that you can use, for example yo can use the windows Sysinternals, they are utilities that can help you in resetting you administrator and other users passwords.  Another option is to use Hirens CD if you have access to it, it also have multiple utilities that will help.  Another option is the ERD Commander from Microsoft, that will help you in resetting the password among other things.

Answer (score 0):

[Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) might be a useful tool, but I don't see anything Ubuntu specific in you question.