# Does anyone know how to reset a Windows 7 Administrator password with Linux?

Tags: uninstall, password, reset

If so, please help and advise.

I do not have a reset disc and I only have one Administrator account.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this, even if it was ever possible then Microsoft would have patched it anyways, as it would be a huge security issue.

Comment: I've read that this is in fact possible, so keep googling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to reset Windows XP administrator password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152965/is-there-a-way-to-reset-windows-xp-administrator-password)

Answer (score 3):

You can't reset Windows Accounts using other OS, but you can reset password from Windows itself. Here is some way I tried before:

1. Insert Windows CD/DVD to you DVD Drive and boot it
2. Choose `repair windows`
3. From there open command prompt
4. Make a copy of exe file called `sethc.exe` (stick Key Program )
5. Change name of original to anything and change `cmd.exe` name to `sethc.exe`
6. Eject the DVD and restart the PC
7. Boot your Windows up to the login screen
8. Click on <kbd>Shift</kbd>key x5 times to initiate the stick key action it will open cmd.exe instead
9. Enter this command and type in it your new password (blank means no password).
10. Close the cmd and log in with your new password.

> net user user_name new_password

**Example**:

> net user Administrator P@$$W0rd

Comment: You CAN use Ubuntu LiveCD to do the file copy/rename (steps 3 & 4), using sudo privileges

Answer (score 0):

You can reset a Windows password with [System Rescue CD](http://sysresccd.org/).  HowToGeek has [some instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-forgotten-windows-password-with-the-linux-system-rescue-cd/).  To summarize:

1. Boot on SystemRescueCD
2. Mount your Windows partition with `ntfs-3g /dev/sdaX /mnt/windows`
3. Change directory to `/mnt/windows/Windows/System32/config`
4. Run `chntpw -u <username> SAM`
5. Select option 1 (clear password) and accept the change and write
6. Un-mount and reboot.

Note: *This must only be done by consent of the computer's owner!*

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility in Hirens Boot CD to reset a user passwords.

[Here are some instructions](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/resetting-windows-password/)

I have used this multiple times with mixed results. I've had alot of luck with Windows XP and some luck with Windows 7, but some of the failed attempts might have been my fault.

I have had more success enabling the system Administrator account and setting the password, rather than changing the password for my admin account.

Anyway, give it a shot and maybe it will work for you.